# Loss graph very strange PyTorch GAN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

I am quite a young coder who has recently gotten into AI and image generation. I've been trying to make a text-to-image GAN but it isn't proving easy. For this one I am using BERT for the text encoder and PyTorch for the neural network: here are the crucial parts of the code, if you need any other details, don't hesitate to ask.

```
def tokenizeText(text, vectorizer):
    vectorized = []
    if len(text[0]) == 1:
        
        tk = vectorizer.tokenize(text)
        tk = vectorizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tk)
        tk = torch.LongTensor(tk)

        vectorized.append(tk)
    elif len(text) > 1:
        for i in text:
            tk = vectorizer.tokenize(i)
            tk = vectorizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tk)
            tk = torch.LongTensor(tk)

            vectorized.append(tk)
        
    

    return vectorized

def prepareText1(textList):
    tk = tokenizeText(textList, vectorizer)

    if len(tk) > 1:
        tknew = []
        for i1 in tk:
            size1 = len(i1)
            size2 = 60 - size1
            zeros = []
            for _ in range(size2):
                zeros.append(0)
            zeros = torch.LongTensor(zeros)
            zeros = zeros.view(1, zeros.size(0))
            i1 = i1.view(1, len(i1))
            tk = torch.cat([i1, zeros], dim=1)
            tknew.append(tk)
            
    return tknew
```

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

        self.inD = np.prod(imgShp) + embedDim
        self.outD = 1

        self.Embedlyr = nn.EmbeddingBag(30000, embedDim)

        self.mainNet = nn.Sequential(

            nn.Linear(self.inD, baseNeurons * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(alpha, True),
            nn.Dropout(dropout),

            nn.Linear(baseNeurons * 4, baseNeurons * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(alpha, True),
            nn.Dropout(dropout),

            nn.Linear(baseNeurons * 2, baseNeurons),
            nn.LeakyReLU(alpha, True),
            nn.Dropout(dropout),

            nn.Linear(baseNeurons, self.outD),
            nn.Sigmoid()

        )

    def forward(self, x, y):
        y = prepareText1(y)
        y = torch.stack(y).squeeze(1)
        y = self.Embedlyr(y)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), np.prod(imgShp))
        x = torch.cat([x, y], dim=1)
        x = self.mainNet(x)

        return x.squeeze(0)

netD = Discriminator().to(device)
optD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        self.inD = nZDim + embedDim
        self.outD = np.prod(imgShp)

        self.Embedlyr = nn.EmbeddingBag(30000, embedDim)

        self.mainNet = nn.Sequential(

            nn.Linear(self.inD, baseNeurons),
            nn.LeakyReLU(alpha, True),

            nn.Linear(baseNeurons, baseNeurons * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(alpha, True),

            nn.Linear(baseNeurons * 2, baseNeurons * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(alpha, True),

            nn.Linear(baseNeurons * 4, self.outD),
            nn.Tanh(),

        )

    def forward(self, x, y):

        y = prepareText1(y)
        y = torch.stack(y).squeeze(1)
        y = self.Embedlyr(y)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), nZDim)
        x = torch.cat([x, y], dim=1)
        x = self.mainNet(x)

        return x.view(x.size(0), cC, imgSz, imgSz)

netG = Generator().to(device)
optG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

```
lossFn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
writer = SummaryWriter()
```

```
def trainStepD(dataInp):
    
    optD.zero_grad()

    imgs = dataInp[0]
    lbls = dataInp[1]

    batchSz1 = imgs.size(0)
    logitLblR = Variable(torch.ones((batchSz, 1))).to(device)
    logitLblF = Variable(torch.zeros((batchSz, 1))).to(device)
    
    output = netD(imgs, lbls)
    lossR = lossFn(output, logitLblR)

    nZ = Variable(torch.randn(batchSz1, nZDim)).to(device)
    output = netG(nZ, lbls)
    output = netD(output, lbls)
    lossF = lossFn(output, logitLblF)

    loss = lossR + lossF
    loss.backward()

    optD.step()

    return loss.data.item()

def trainStepG(dataInp):

    optG.zero_grad()

    imgs = dataInp[0]
    lbls = dataInp[1]

    batchSz1 = imgs.size(0)
    logitLblR = Variable(torch.ones((batchSz, 1))).to(device)

    nZ = Variable(torch.randn(batchSz1, nZDim)).to(device)
    output = netG(nZ, lbls)
    output = netD(output, lbls)

    loss = lossFn(output, logitLblR)
    loss.backward()

    optG.step()

    return loss.data.item()
```

```
epochs = 50
displayStep = 5
criticNo = 5

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print('Initializing Epoch [{}/{}]...'.format((epoch + 1), epochs), end=' ')

    for batchNo, dataInp in enumerate(dLoader):
        
        step = epoch * len(dLoader) + batchNo + 1

        batchSz1 = dataInp[0].size(0)

        netG.train()
        for _ in range(criticNo):
            DLoss = trainStepD(dataInp)

        GLoss = trainStepG(dataInp)

        writer.add_scalars('scalars', {'GLoss': GLoss, 'DLoss': (DLoss / criticNo)}, step)  

        if step % displayStep == 0:
            netG.eval()
            z = Variable(torch.randn(9, nZDim)).to(device)
            labels = []
            for i in range(9):
                labels.append(dataInp[1][i])
            sample_images = netG(z, labels)
            grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(sample_images, nrow=3, normalize=True)
            writer.add_image("Batch Results", grid, step)
            
    print('Done!')
```

These are the results I got from this:

**Loss graph, Green - Discriminator Loss, Pink - Generator Loss:**

[image: Loss graph, Green - Discriminator Loss, Pink - Generator Loss:]

My dataset is just a small folder of blue and red images labeled blue or red.

**Dataset:**

[image: Dataset]
Please let me know if anyone can help.
Thanks

Comment: I have fixed it somewhat, the loss graph isn't so weird, but now I think its just overfitting due to a tiny dataset.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.